# how to keep background(zero values) transparent while converting array to shapefile?

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, shapefile, qgis

I have predicted binary mask and converted it to shapefile after that I saved this vector file. But when I opened that file in QGIS it showed only borders, It doesn't make it with transparent background (which is zero values in binary mask). How can I make the background transparent? Here is codes that I have used and image :

```
def convert_array_to_vector(binary_mask: np.array, img_path: str) -> gpd.GeoDataFrame:
    """Convert masked array to vector file(.shp).

    Args:
        binary_mask: Output predicted binary mask.
        img_path: Path of the raster file used for the prediction.

    Returns:
        shp: GeoPandas DataFrame.

    """
    with rasterio.open(img_path, mode='r') as src:
        mask_meta = src.meta.copy()
        mask_meta.update(
            {
                'dtype': 'uint8',
                'count': 1,
                'nodata': 0.0
            }
        )

        with MemoryFile() as memfile:
            with memfile.open(**mask_meta) as mem:
                mem.write_band(1, binary_mask)
                geoms = dataset_features(
                    mem,
                    geographic=False,
                    as_mask=True,
                    with_nodata=True
                )
                shp = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(
                    geoms,
                    crs=str(mem.crs).lower(),
                    columns=['geometry', 'val']
                )
    return shp

def save_vector_file(shp: gpd.GeoDataFrame, dest_path: str) -> None:
    """Write vector file to the disk.

    Args:
        dest_path: Destionation path to save the vector file.
        shp: vector dataframe.

    """
    shp.to_file(dest_path)
```

Converted Image:
[image]

Image that I want to have:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried passing `with_nodata=False` in your call to `dataset_features()`?